# How can this series pass the structural change test?

Tags: r, variance, structural-change

I have this series:

```
r <- c(14.1649994,17.3997831,32.8877030,6.1547551,6.3594748,101.9584077,196.8411517,23.8292043,11.7583992,2.2915478,5.5088687,16.8188390,2.3077979,2.6666377,2.0955362,0.9319688,0.6688078,1.0523184,6.8158264,13.1813211,17.8467944,1.9876636,7.0219306,3.9272217,4.3325448,7.8778125,1.1878058,1.7207762,2.9655665,5.8571428)
```

I'm using the `strucchange` package to detect the structural changes. The result is:

```
> sctest(r~1)

    Recursive CUSUM test

 data:  r ~ 1 
 S = 0.7785, p-value = 0.1579
```

How is it possible that the test didn't detect changes? There is a very big move rising around 200.

Take a look at the plot of the series below.
[image]

Comment: `sctest(r~1, type="Chow", point=7)`

Comment: @Brandon, I have to do it programmatically, I don't know the point with the break, in this case yes because I have checked it visually, but in the case I can't see it, what method should i use? how is it possible this break is not detected?

Comment: To me, an outlier test (like Grubbs) seems more approriate. Run this code and take a peak to see why your test "seems" to fail. `r.cus <- efp(r~1, type="Rec-CUSUM")` and then `plot(r.cus)`. Here's a related paper on the topic. http://blogperso.univ-rennes1.fr/arthur.charpentier/public/strucchange.pdf

Comment: @Brandon I have seen that function but seem there is not a  p-value to understand if the test pass or not.

Comment: `library(outliers);grubbs.test(r); grubbs.test(r)$p-value;dixon.test(r,type=22)` note that these only test to see if there is ONE outlier.

Comment: But, you should probably update your question to reflect your reason for looking for a structural change in such a small data set. Usually, I only look for structural change in larger time series data to assist in identifying if different time periods should be modeled seperately...

Comment: @Brandon I can't use a large dataset because these numbers are the residuals of a linear regression (stock price series) 99% of the time there is a change...i only need to find "big" change. i'm worry that these outliers methos will find "outlier" always.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1301/discussion-between-brandon-bertelsen-and-dail)